# Locating the POST request URL authorization key in Cake PHP

Tags: ios, cakephp, swift3, alamofire

I am using Alamofire with my CakePHP API to request a POST. While following [this documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#making-a-request) it asks for a HTTP Headers, however I am unsure where to locate the 'Authorization' and 'Accept' key in my site directory. Would this be located inside the directory or elsewhere?

This is where I have gotten with my request function:

```
func myImageUploadRequest() {

    Alamofire.request("http://178.62.107.243/posts", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)

}

enum HTTPMethod: String {
        case post = "POST"
    }

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "id": post.id,
    "file_name": post.fileName,
    "artist_id": post.artistId
]

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "",
        "Accept": ""
    ]
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to set any HTTP headers. It depends on the settings of your API whether you need to set up any or not.
The accept header specifies for the API in what format is your request body (usually application/json or application/xml) while authorization contains the authorization token if your API expects any.